# Searching for matches between .so and .exe

Tags: shared-libraries, disassembly, portable-executable

I need to determine all the potential relationships between the functions of the `.so` android library and the `.exe` files of Windows.

With virtual functions there are no problems, but how to find member functions and static functions in an `.exe` file?
Are there any tools for this?
Or any other way to achieve this?